# Checking additional conditions for product price in magento

Tags: magento

In my magento site i added number of products with price as 0.00.

Now that products are displayed with price as $0.00.

so i want to display the price as `not mentioned` instead of `$0.00`.

How can i do this?

the price.phtml what is the condition i need to write for that?

My condition is:

```
if price == 0.00 display the text 'not mentioned'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
    <?php 
        if ((int)$this->getPrice()){
            echo $this->getPrice();
        }else {
            echo "not mentioned";
        } 
    ?>
```

correct me if i am wrong.

^^